# game.make is undefined in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, game-engine, phaser-framework

My code is showing "TypeError: game.make is undefined" for the below code in Phaser 3.

```
var config = {
     type: Phaser.AUTO,
     width: 800,
     height: 600,
     scene: {
         preload: preload,
         create: create,
         update: update
     }
 };

 var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
 var bmd; 
function create() {
         this.add.image(400, 300, 'paper');
         bmd = game.make.bitmapData(800, 600);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything in Phaser 3 is Scene based. You shouldn't access any systems directly off `game` any more. So swap it for `this.make` instead. Also, there is no BitmapData object in Phaser 3, so you'll have to change that part too.

Comment: What has "BitmapData" object been replaced with ?